# Finding the radius of convergence of $\sum\frac{(n+1)z^n}{n!}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the radius of convergence $R$ of the complex series $\sum\frac{(n+1)z^n}{n!}$. I understand that $R=\infty$, but I need a little help understanding one line of the process.

I use the fact that $R=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\right|$. Here, $a_n=\frac{n+1}{n!}$, so $a_{n-1}=\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$. Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n.n!}{(n+1)(n-1)!}$. All is well up until this point.

I am struggling with finding this limit. My textbook says $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n.n!}{(n+1)(n-1)!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n$, with no explanation of how that conclusion was reached. I attempted to divide the numerator and denominator by $n!$ and got $\frac{n.n!}{(n+1)(n-1)!}=\frac{n}{\frac{n+1}{n!}\frac{n-1}{n!}}=\frac{n}{\frac{n+1}{n!}\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{n^2.n!}{n+1}$ - not the result I was looking for.

Any help would be appreciated very much!

Comment: You've made a mistake when dividing the denominator by $n!$.

Comment: This series is $\partial_z \sum \frac{z^{n+1}}{n!}$. You can look at radius of convergence of $\frac{1}{z} \sum \frac{z^n}{n!}$

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot ...\cdot (n-1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot ...\cdot (n-1)\cdot n}=\frac{1}{n},$$
you have

$$\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\right|=\frac{\frac{n+1}{n!}}{\frac{n}{(n-1)!}}=\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot \frac{(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n}\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0.$$